# Calculate running total per month

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

Let's say I have this table:

```
id; date; units
1; Jan 1; 1
2; Jan 2; 4
3; Feb 9; 6
4; Mar 1; 1
5; Mar 4; 2
```

How can I now calculate the "accumulated_month" column accordingly? The calculation should start anew with every new month.

```
id; date; units; accumulated_month
1; Jan 1; 1; 1
2; Jan 2; 4; 5
3; Feb 9; 6; 6
4; Mar 1; 1; 1
5; Mar 4; 2; 3
```

All I manage to get is this:

```
id; date; units; accumulated_month
1; Jan 1; 1; 5
2; Jan 2; 4; 5
3; Feb 9; 6; 6
4; Mar 1; 1; 3
5; Mar 4; 2; 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t1.date, 
    t1.units,
    SUM(t2.units) accumulated_month
FROM t t1 
    JOIN t t2 
        ON date_trunc('month', t1.date) = date_trunc('month', t2.date)
            AND t2.date <= t1.date
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date, t1.units
ORDER BY t1.id
```

## EDIT:

Simplified SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.*, SUM(t2.units) accumulated_month
FROM t t1 
    JOIN t t2 
        ON date_trunc('month', t1.date) = date_trunc('month', t2.date)
            AND t2.date <= t1.date
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

### Logic

The logic behind is to `JOIN` the table with itself. Then for each row of `t1` `JOIN` all rows in `t2` that satisfies both (`AND`):

1. same year/month
2. t2.date <= t1.date

With those `ON` constraints each row in `t1` will be `JOIN` with accumulated in that month so far. So without grouping, you'd get something like:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║    date    ║ units ║  t2_date   ║ t2_units ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ 2016-01-01 ║     1 ║ 2016-01-01 ║        1 ║
║  2 ║ 2016-01-02 ║     4 ║ 2016-01-01 ║        1 ║
║  2 ║ 2016-01-02 ║     4 ║ 2016-01-02 ║        4 ║
║  3 ║ 2016-02-09 ║     6 ║ 2016-02-09 ║        6 ║
║  4 ║ 2016-03-01 ║     1 ║ 2016-03-01 ║        1 ║
║  5 ║ 2016-03-04 ║     2 ║ 2016-03-01 ║        1 ║
║  5 ║ 2016-03-04 ║     2 ║ 2016-03-04 ║        2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

After `GROUP BY t1.id` you can `SUM(t2.units)` to get what you expect.

Comment: Terrific! That worked. Could you maybe explain me the logic behind? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
create table t (id int, date date, units int);
insert into t (id, date, units) values
(1, '2016-01-01', 1),
(2, '2016-01-02', 4),
(3, '2016-02-09', 6),
(4, '2016-03-01', 1),
(5, '2016-03-04', 2);
```

Not clear if you want the month total or a running total within the month. For the month total:

```
select
    id, date, units,
    sum(units) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date)) as acumm
from t
order by 1,2
;
 id |    date    | units | acumm 
----+------------+-------+-------
  1 | 2016-01-01 |     1 |     5
  2 | 2016-01-02 |     4 |     5
  3 | 2016-02-09 |     6 |     6
  4 | 2016-03-01 |     1 |     3
  5 | 2016-03-04 |     2 |     3
```

If you want a running total within the month then add an order by to the window function:

```
select
    id, date, units,
    sum(units) over (
        partition by date_trunc('month', date)
        order by id
    ) as acumm
from t
order by 1,2
;
 id |    date    | units | acumm 
----+------------+-------+-------
  1 | 2016-01-01 |     1 |     1
  2 | 2016-01-02 |     4 |     5
  3 | 2016-02-09 |     6 |     6
  4 | 2016-03-01 |     1 |     1
  5 | 2016-03-04 |     2 |     3
```

Comment: maybe you could explain the query, so others will better benefit from your answer

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for me, as I keep getting the monthly YTD total value for each day in a month. Not sure if I did something wrong?

Comment: @user3716424 Works for me. Check the updated answer with data.